# How to prove that $\frac{1000!}{(500!)^2}$ is not divisible by 7?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial

> How to prove that 
>   $$\frac{1000!}{(500!)^2}$$
>   is not divisible by 7?

I reduced the above fraction to:
$$\frac{\prod_{k=501}^{1000}k}{500!} $$

But I don't know how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: Hint: consider prime factorisations. Focus on $7$'s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a general formula that the number of times a prime $p$ occurs in the prime factorisation of $n!$ is given by

$$
\left[\frac{n}{p}\right] + \left[\frac{n}{p^2}\right] + \left[\frac{n}{p^3}\right] + \cdots
$$

where $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer $≤x$.

In $1000!$ you'd have

$$
\left[\frac{1000}{7}\right] + \left[\frac{1000}{7^2}\right] + \left[\frac{1000}{7^3}\right] + \cdots = 164
$$

$7$'s, and in $500!$ you have

$$
\left[\frac{500}{7}\right] + \left[\frac{500}{7^2}\right] + \left[\frac{500}{7^3}\right] + \cdots = 82
$$

$7$'s. So you'll have a total of $164$ 7's in $(500!)^2$.

The rest follows.

Comment: I am sorry but would you kindly help in the conclusion? I scratched my head for a while but did not understand how that proves that it is not divisible by 7.

Answer (score 25):

This is overkill, but by [Lucas's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas's_theorem)$$\frac{1000!}{(500!)^2}=\binom{1000}{500} \equiv \binom{2}{1}\binom{6}{3}\binom{2}{1}\binom{6}{3} \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$$
As $1000=2626_{7}$ and $500=1313_{7}$.

Here is another , more elementary argument, from [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_formula),  $$\nu_7(n!) = \frac{n - s_7(n)}{6}$$
So $\nu_7(100!)=164, \nu_7 (50!)=82$. So the $7$ s in the denominator and the numerator cancel out. So we have the desired result.

Comment: Got it! But you told that applying Lucas's Theorem is overkill, so, is there any other solution?

Comment: @AmitayasBanerjee I added one right now. This one is a more elementary result.

Comment: (+1) Two beautiful proofs in a single answer make a well-deserved upvote.

Comment: [+1] I love Lucas' theorem, and a good application of it.

Comment: @AmitayasBanerjee Could you tell me why you unaccepted my answer?

Answer (score 5):

You can also overkill it by Kummer's theorem:

Notice that $500$ is $1313$ in base $7$. Since every digit is smaller than $\frac{7}{2}$ there are no carries when adding $1313+1313$ in base $7$.

Therefore $\binom{1000}{500}$ is not a multiple of $7$.

---

In general we have that a prime $p$ divides $\binom{2n}{n}$ if and only if $n$ has at least one digit larger than or equal to  $p/2$ in its base $p$ expansion.

Answer (score 4):

Consider prime factorisations:

$$\lfloor\frac{1000}{7}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{1000}{7^2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{1000}{7^3}\rfloor+...=142+20+2=164$$
Then $$7^{164}|1000!$$

Similarly:

$$\lfloor\frac{500}{7}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{500}{7^2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{500}{7^3}\rfloor+...=71+10+1=82$$
Then $$7^{164}=7^{82\cdot2}=(7^{82})^2|(500!)^2$$

Comment: Sorry, but didn't get it.

Comment: The fact that $7^{164}$ divides $1000!$ and $(500!)^2$ does not suffice to decide if $7$ divides their ratio or not. Please be more careful.

Comment: Yes. But I considered prime factorisations

Comment: So the point is not that $7^{164}$ divides $1000!$, but that $7^{165}$ does not.

Comment: I'm understood, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In $\{1,\dots, 500\}$, there are 71 multiples of 7, 10 multiples of $7^2$ and one multiple of $7^3$.
How many multiples of $7$, $7^2$, $7^3$ do you have in $\{501,\dots, 1000\}$? Same amount.

Comment: Why are they the same amount?

Comment: 504 is first multiple of 7 (with multiplicity of seven is 1 in factorization), and $504 + 7 \cdot 70 = 994$. Also $7^2 \cdot 11 = 539$ (multiplicity is 2) and $7^2 \cdot 20 = 980$. At last $7^3 \cdot 2 = 686$ (fits only once).